# Mixing GoogleTest EXPECT_CALL with EXPECT_DEATH

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I have an example where `exit(-1)` is called at the end of the logic flow.
I am trying to test this flow with gMock/gTest expectation.

I have the following example:

```
class A {
  public:
    virtual void Bar() = 0;
    void Foo() {

        Bar();
        exit(-1);
    }
};
class AMocked : public A {
  public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(Bar, void());
};


TEST(MyDeathTest,
     MyTest) {
    AMocked am;
    EXPECT_CALL(am, Bar()).Times(51);

    auto f = [&]() {
        am.Foo();
    };
    EXPECT_DEATH(f(),"");
}
```

I have tried a lot of combination, where to put the `EXPECT_CALL` inside the lambda or outside it and the EXPECT_CALL is not checked.

gTest used: 1.8/1.12.

Comment: EPXECT is a typo, right?

Comment: @273K, Looks like I missed the last line while I was copying the code.

Comment: @273K I don't think this is exactly related to the linked question as a duplicate.

Comment: @Ari You are not right. This is the exact duplicate and explains that `EXPECT_CALL` is set in one process, but `f()` is called in another process. If you set the expectation `EXPECT_CALL(am, Bar()).Times(0);`, then you will get `Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(am, Bar())` in the first process.

Comment: It's the exact duplicate, but it seems a hard question to grasp. ( or at least for me ).
I think the only way right now is to use `cerr` as caught by death test or to wrap exit calls in an abstract interface, have a concrete implementation for real app and another mocked for testing.
Unit testing can teach you a lot.

Comment: @273K Please see my comment under the accepted answer in the question you linked. I think the test still fails even with the suggested fix. Moreover, OP is using the mock object in incorrectly. I was in the middle of fixing that in my answer, but the question got closed.